# Ruby on Rails: how to get value of number_field in code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formbuilder, formhelper

I'm new to Ruby and obviously RoR.  I used a scaffold to create a rails project.  For the model I required two fields, num1:integer and num2:integer.  The view that was made to create those two fields was

```
<%= form_for(@calculation) do |f| %>
    .
    .
    .
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :num1 %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :num1 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :num2 %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :num2 %>
  </div>
```

I've been all over the internet and cannot find how to get the values that are entered into those fields in order to manipulate them.  Here is what I have

```
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.button('Add', &Calculation.add(:num1,:num2)) %>
  </div>
```

In the above code I am trying to create a button that will run the Calculation.add method with the values from the number_fields as the numbers to add.  With what I have I keep getting an error: "undefined method `+' for :num1:Symbol".  I'm thinking that the num1 and num2 are just the names of the number_fields and so I need to know how to get the integers that are entered into those fields.  Thanks for your help. Oh, and I'm using Ruby 193 and Rails 4.0 with the RubyMine IDE.

EDIT

Here is the model code.  I'm sure its ugly for a real rubyist to see:

```
class Calculation < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.add (x,y)
    x+y
  end

  def self.subtract(x,y)
    x-y
  end

  def self.multiply(x,y)
    x*y
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you add the model definition?

Comment: you mean you want to manipulate the values inserted client side inside Ruby (server side) views?

Comment: @mdesantis Yea I guess... I want something like a .getValue for the number_fields that returns the number inside the field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit the data from the form to a controller action server-side in order to use ruby Model code on it. It seems like you are trying to do client-side behavior (javascript) instead of server-side (Ruby on Rails)

Answer (score 0):

Server side you can't know which value the user inserted *before* the user submits the form.

So, if you want to manipulate the data before the form submission you should implement your `Calculation` client side (read: using javascript), otherwise you have to capture the form response in the controller action and manipulate the user data, which will be present inside the `params` controller variable.